# using a class within a class on java

Tags: java, class

```
import java.util.*;

public class Lab21_Vars {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int i = 0;
        int j = 0;
        int var0, var1;

        // Fix 1: Correctly typecast 5.0 to an int so it can assigned to var3.
        int var2 = 0, var3 = (int) 5.0;

        // Fix 2: Correctly declare a variable as an array.
        int[] arri0 = {10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1};

        double[] arrd0 = {0.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0};

        // Fix 3: What's wrong with temp? Fix it.
        int temp = 0;
        if (i < j) {
            System.out.println("Temp is " + temp);
        } 
        else {
            System.out.println("Temp is " + temp);
        }

        // Fix 4: Correctly calculate square of sums and print it as total.
        int total = 0;

        for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            total += i*i;
        }
        System.out.println("i value is " + i);
        System.out.println("Total is " + total);

        // Fix 5: Figure out the logical error in lines 36-42, and correct it.
        Cheese jack;
        Cheese monterey = new Cheese("Monterey");
        jack = monterey;
        System.out.println("Monterey name is " + monterey.getName());
        jack.setName("Jack");
        System.out.println("Jack name is " + jack.getName());
        System.out.println("Monterey name is still " + monterey.getName());

        // Fix 6: Make the following code shorter by combining redundant 
        //        (unnecessary/duplicate) statements
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter first number: ");
        int num1 = input.nextInt();

        {
            System.out.print("Enter second number: ");
            int num2 = input.nextInt();

            if (num1 > var3 )
                System.out.println("First is greater");
            else
                System.out.println("First is Less than or equal");


            if (num2 < var3)
                System.out.println("Second is Less");   
            else
                System.out.println("Second is greater than or equal to");

            System.out.println("The first number was " + num1);

        }

    }
}
```

Most of my code is working, however the cheese part is not. I know I need to create another class so that the code can work. Do I need to create different constructors with different functions? I tried creating the cheese class myself but I was not on the right track. From what I know the class will be on a different java project but as I mentioned I can't get it to work. Any help is very appreciated

Comment: Please show us some effort, in what you tried already... Then we can get you back on track...

Comment: "Most of my code is working, however the cheese part is not." It would be helpful if you'd restrict your question to *just* the part that's not working then. Edit your question to *just* the problematic code, show what you've tried, and what problems you ran into.

Comment: Since you haven't said what your code is _supposed_ to do, it's impossible to tell you how to make it do what you want.  Voting to close.

Answer (score 1):

//Fix 5
when you assign
`jack = monterey;`

you are just making reference to same object in memory therefore when you print

```
jack.getName() and monterey.getName()
```

Both will give same value as they are pointing to single object. 
Instead of directly assigning make new function in cheese class to clone object using new keyword.